# Different zPositions relative to different Nodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Let's say I have nodes A, B, and C. How would I set node A to a higher zPosition that node B, set node B to a higher zPosition than C, BUT set node A to a lower zPosition than node C. Basically, only show node A while above node B, and hide it while behind node C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. To show node A above B and hide A behind C means that you need C to be above both A and B. But then you need B to be higher than C, which means that C can't be above B. Try it with pieces of paper on a desk and you will see that you can't meet both objectives...

Comment: You forget, this is the computers we are dealing with, not real life.  Just need to constantly change zPosition

Comment: @BCode Not sure if this will suit your needs, but you could consider adding a child node to C. Give that child node a z position that will hide A. Then give node C a position that will be below B, (but such that the child node still hides A). So there will be a part of C that hides A, and a part of C that is below B. If you try this, just remember that z position of a node is relative to its parent. So the absolute global z position of a node is its z position + its parent's z position + its parent's parent's z position, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up contact detection between the nodes without collision detection, so that they are able to overlap and you get notified when they do.

When they start to overlap, (i.e. `didBegin` is called for the nodes you are interested in) adjust each node's z-Position accordingly. Implement some rules so that if all 3 are overlapping, you get sensible results.